# Infinite energy from net charge of a closed, finite universe

Tags: energy, electric-fields, universe

I have read that a net charge in a closed, finite universe would result in the electric field from the charge "winding" forever which would lead to infinite energy. However, wouldn't the electric field lines cancel out if they were winding around the surface of a sphere like in the diagram? [image]

Comment: Where did you read it?

Comment: In Steven Weinberg's The First Three Minutes.